# How do I set different file paths between development and deployment?

Tags: java, maven

I have an object that takes in a string for a config.xml file. I have it set to the resources folder while developing, but how would I go about changing it to a different location when I build the project?

Comment: Please show code how you pass that path to config.xml. The answer depends on that.

Comment: It's simply: new MyObject("src/main/resources/config.xml");

Comment: Am I correct that for Prod usage you are going to use another path to that file like `new MyObject("/a/b/c/prod_config.xml")`? If yes then you need to change your code to pass filename from external source not to hardcode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of profiles and filtering for that. Use these bits in the pom.xml

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>development</id>
    <properties>
      <somevalue>development value</somevalue>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  ...
</profiles>

<build>
  ...
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

Assumming you have a "somevalue" variable in your `config.xml` like:

```
<property name="someproperty" value="${somevalue}"/>
```

Maven will replace the value with the specified value in your profile section when it writes the `config.xml` file to the `target` directory, as long as you have enabled "filtering" in the resources section.

[Here is an introduction to maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for something very simple, what I've often seen is the app will actually contain most if not all the config in multiple "myapp.${env}.properties" file (spring syntax, but the same thing can be done in plain Java also) where "env" gets defined at launch using java's "-Denv=". If some of the config needs to be external to the app itself (because it contains passwords for example) then just have the path to that file configured in the environment-specific .properties file. You just have to launch the app with the right -D in each environment, or have those define as environment variables to start with so you don't have to remember to add it on the command-line for every single app.

You can also take a look at [Apache's common-config](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) if you want something more complex.